# What does "apachesolr_access_node_ignore = 1" mean?

Tags: 7, search

What does `apachesolr_access_node_ignore => 1` mean?

Does it affect the search, when `apachesolr_access_node_ignore` is set to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't affect search. Basically, `$node->apachesolr_access_node_ignore` is set to 1 in `hook_node_insert()` or `hook_node_update()` by the *Apache SOLR Access* module for ignoring node that is already index.

Comment: Thanks... What is mean by [apachesolr_access_node_ignore] => 1 ?Can you please explain it?

Comment: @steniya if you set the value to 1 means Apache Solr will not reindex the node but if you want to index your node every time with new value then set it to 0.